# Why pytesseract is slower on segmented characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I got an image with '105'.

My preprocessing turns it to black and white, and makes it big (300dpi) and cleans it.

When I run this with the whole image/word:

```
pytesseract.image_to_string(img, None, False, "-psm 8 digits")
```

It reads the entire image and the result is accurate, (8 option is for single word).

Why if I segment the characters, and send them one by one the '1' , '0' , '5' , it takes 3 times longer to process the results (I am not counting the added time in preprocess work (segmentation).

I am using this for each of the segmented characters:

```
pytesseract.image_to_string(img_orig, None, False, "-psm 10 digits")
```

(10 option is for single character, but I tried pretty much all options and get the same time result)

Characters are at the same sizes as the whole word, Running it with a thread function and i got the same results.

'Helping' tesseract with segmentation of the characters, should be faster than sending the whole word which is a bigger image because so much useless space between characters, no?